# useInfiniteQuery doesnt go to the next page

Tags: react-native, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll, react-query

I have this code in react native, where i am trying to implement ***react-query***:

```
  const { data, isLoading, error, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, refetch } =
    useInfiniteQuery<BovinePaginator, Error>(
      [API_ENDPOINTS.BOVINE_IDENTIFICATION, options],
      ({ queryKey }) => client.bovine.all(queryKey[1] as object),
      {
        getNextPageParam: ({ meta }) => meta.last_page > meta.current_page && { page: meta.current_page + 1 },
        enabled: false,
      },
    );
```

My problem is in the getNextPageParam where meta has this response:

```
{"current_page": 1, "from": 1, "last_page": 2051, "path":"url_here", "per_page": "10", "to": 10, "total": 20507}
```

The problem is that current_page doesn't update its value and stays 1. And the refetch keeps returning in infinite the same first values. Any idea how to fix it ??

**Thank you!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this as a permanant solution:

I apologize for the oversight. You are correct; the `allPages` parameter in the `getNextPageParam` function is not being used in the code. Let's revise the code to use `allPages` correctly to determine whether there are more pages to fetch:

```js
const { data, isLoading, error, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, refetch } =
  useInfiniteQuery<BovinePaginator, Error>(
    [API_ENDPOINTS.BOVINE_IDENTIFICATION, options],
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
      // Use pageParam instead of hardcoding the page number
      return client.bovine.all({ ...options, page: pageParam });
    },
    {
      // Use getNextPageParam to determine when to fetch the next page
      getNextPageParam: (_, allPages) => {
        // Check if there are more pages to fetch
        const lastPage = allPages[allPages.length - 1];
        if (lastPage.meta.current_page < lastPage.meta.last_page) {
          // Increment the current page by 1 for the next fetch
          return lastPage.meta.current_page + 1;
        } else {
          // No more pages to fetch
          return undefined;
        }
      },
      enabled: false,
    },
  );
```

In this revised code:

1. We use `allPages` to access the last page of data fetched. `allPages` is an array containing all previously fetched pages, and we use the last page to determine if there are more pages to fetch.
2. We check if there are more pages to fetch by comparing the `current_page` of the last page with the `last_page`. If there are more pages, we increment the current page by 1 for the next fetch. If not, we return `undefined` to indicate that there are no more pages to fetch.

This should ensure that the `getNextPageParam` function works correctly to fetch additional pages when needed.